# How to access the table AspNetUserRoles generated by ASP identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I am coding an API that uses the Identity feature on asp.net and right now I am trying to make a method that returns all the couples ( `user.id`, `role.id` ) which are stored on the table `AspNetUserRoles` when assigning a role to a user.

One solution would be to get the full list of users and find each role of that user in a double loop but having too much data, it wouldn't be optimal for my case. The perfect solution for me would be to access that table directly which contains exactly what I am looking for

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create class models and relationships explicitly as described in the documentation below:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1#add-user-and-role-navigation-properties

This documentation expects you to at least create the ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole and ApplicationUserRole class models. Also, you will have to update your DBContext accordingly to correctly use the new models that you create. The names for the models can be changed. However, in any case, this should not change any DB schema and will not require any EF migrations.

Lastly,